# ajuda no github

Tags: php, javascript, json, pwa

Olá, sou ainda um bebe no universo da programação e está é minha primeira interação com o stackoverflow, então por favor se eu fizer alguma besteira por favor me ajudem.

link para o github: [Projeto Recicla Óleo](https://github.com/Bobson360/recycle-cooking-oil)

Tenho um projeto no github, na verdade um rascunho de projeto, este projeto foi escrito por mim para resolver um problema do meu trabalho, trabalho com reciclagem de óleo em residências, "igual aqueles caras que passam uns 10 a cada hora vendendo ovo ou pamonha com auto falante", a diferença é que eu peço óleo...kk
Pois bem, este tem sido meu sustento a cinco anos e existem ruas que eu já passo a quase cinco anos pelo menos uma vez ao mês e ainda assim varias pessoas me dizem, "nossa, é a primeira vez que você está passando?". Então resolvi pesquisar o por que as pessoas não sabem que a cinco anos eu passo na rua dela pegando óleo, o resultado foi unanime, estas pessoas estavam em horário de trabalho as outras vezes que passei. tentando resolver este problema eu escrevi o projeto de uma aplicação que amenizaria este problema, não só para mim e as regiões onde atendo, mas podendo se tornar um projeto de abrangência nacional ou até mesmo internacional. mas ai percebi que minhas habilidades hobbistas em programação não seriam o suficiente para desenvolver este projeto, então fiz uma cotação de quanto custaria pagar por isso, R$ 40.000,00 só para começar.
então resolvi tornar o projeto publico.

se alguém puder colaborar mesmo que seja divulgando ou melhorando as especificações, já seria de grande ajuda.

segue o link do github: [Projeto Recicla Óleo](https://github.com/Bobson360/recycle-cooking-oil)

Comment: Olá Robson. Marquei a sua postagem como fora de escopo porque está fora do que tratamos aqui no site. O formato é de perguntas e respostas. Se tiver dúvidas de programação no desenvolvimento da sua plataforma, pode postar outras perguntas. Mas somente divulgar o projeto está fora do formato daqui.

Comment: ok, foi minha primeira postagem, não li ainda as regras da plataforma. obrigado.